# Measurement Protocol events in Google Analytics do no appear

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm currently adding some tracking in my app with the `Measurement Protocol`. When I use it in dev/staging, it works like a charm, however when I am targeting production, it doesn't work anymore.

I've already try a bunch of tests and I know for sure that the problem isn't in my code: When I test with my old id (`UA-xxx-1`) it doesn't work, but when I create a new app (`UA-xxx-2`) it does work.

That's why I suspect I may have misconfigured something on the Google Analytics side.

Does anyone has an idea about what it could be?

I don't want to use a new web property since I already have a large amount historic data in the old one.

Comment: Are you checking the realtime reports or the standard reports?

Comment: I've checked both of them. But for now, I'm focusing on the realtime reports for my 2 apps. And the same event (I only change the `tid`), sent at the same time works on 1 app, and not on the other.

Comment: Want to add the code for the hit you are sending?

Comment: The issue isn't with my code but with the configuration of my view (since it works with a brand new app). I'm currently copying the same configuration as in my non-working-app into my working-app until I discover the one causing the pb. I'll post the result here.

Comment: Without being able to test your code I'm afraid I cant be of anymore help.   I think you should post screen shots of your account setup and what you are sending to the measurement protocol.

Comment: You're right. Another member sent me some clues and with your "*you should post screen shots of your account setup*", I did find the solution of my pb: I had an old filter on the `Browser Size` which filtered all the requests with empty values. I've removed this useless filter and I start receiving back my event :) Thx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the origin of the missing data: I had an old filter removing all the requests without `Browser Size` filled in.

Thx for the help.